# Fix Host header attack Vulnerability in Codeigniter

Tags: php, header, host

I was asked to solve a security issue in a codeigniter application hosted on a windows server **IIS** and here is the description of the issue. I believe it has come from reporting software called "Acunetix".

> Host header attack
>
> Vulnerability description
>
> An attacker can manipulate the Host header as seen by the web application and cause the application to behave in unexpected ways. Developers often resort to the exceedingly untrustworthy HTTP Host header         (_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] in PHP). Even otherwise-secure applications trust this value enough to write it to the page without HTML-encoding it with code equivalent to:
>
> ```
>    <link href="http://_SERVER['HOST']"    (Joomla)
>    ...and append secret keys and tokens to links containing it: 
>    <a href="http://_SERVER['HOST']?token=topsecret">  (Django, Gallery, others)
>    ....and even directly import scripts from it: 
>    <script src="http://_SERVER['HOST']/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4">  (Various)
> ```
>
> Affected items
>
> - /techP/user/forget
> - /techP/user/login
> - /techP/user/loginexec
> - /techP/user/register
>
> The impact of this vulnerability
>
> An attacker can manipulate the Host header as seen by the web application and cause the application to behave in unexpected ways.
>
> How to fix this vulnerability
>
> The web application should use the SERVER_NAME instead of the Host header. It should also create a dummy vhost that catches all requests with unrecognized Host headers. This can also be done under Nginx     by specifying a non-wildcard SERVER_NAME, and under Apache by using a non-wildcard serverName and turning the UseCanonicalName directive on. Consult references for detailed information.

I did not understand what the actual problem is, so can some one explain briefly how to fix this?

Comment: Won't upgrading CodeIgniter to the latest version fix it?

Comment: Where have the instructions to fix it come from? Clearly that's not your writing, so could you add some context to that?

Comment: This app is not developed by me, it has been handed over to me. After deployment, the organisation which uses this app made a report containing security issues with that app. I've searched the web and found that they used an application called acunetix.

Comment: Would you edit into the question what web server you are using? Apache/IIS?

Answer (score 1):

This vulnerability, as I understand it, primarily affects sites that are the default vhost for an IP address. That is to say that, regardless of the `Host` HTTP header sent by the client, the site will be served regardless. Sites that are the only configured site on an HTTP server will sometimes be set up like this.

Sites that are virtually hosted (i.e. they *require* a valid `Host` header) could still be vulnerable, since [some attacks send multiple copies of the header](http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html) (see in particular the section on 'Cache poisoning').

Your first step is to replicate this. Set up the app on a local Apache instance and try to replicate the specific vulnerability mentioned. To do this you'll need to get it to respond to IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) as well as `localhost`. Once you have done that, you can use header modification tools (e.g. via `curl` or browser plugins) to modify the `Host` value as it is sent to the client.

Try creating these situations:

- A domain unrelated to the actual domain in use, controlled by you, to see if you can persuade the app to redirect to your domain
- Inject a domain with an XSS hack in it

Once you have demonstrated the attack, find out where the host has been specifically read, and replace it with a configured version. This, of course, will need to be environment-specific.

Comment: How to achieve this on windows server 2008 ?

Comment: Well, security testing is a broad topic. Are you able to set this up on a test machine, on a primary vhost, so it responds to an IP address? That is the first step. Then browser tools in Firefox or Chrome can inject headers, change access methods e.g. the Network tab in FF.

Comment: I have the application set up on a windows server which I have direct access to, and chrome browser installed on it.

Comment: Right. Are you familiar with HTTP at all? You'll need to be in order to tackle this problem. You could of course just replace all instances of `$_SERVER['HOST']` with a fixed string, but unless you can show it has this vulnerability before you fix it, and then show it does not after you fix it, you won't really know. Do you have in-house expertise that can help you? Or can you get a freelancer to help?

Comment: $_SERVER['HOST'] is not used in the web application, so I don't know why it is mentioned in the report ?

Comment: Neither do I. Ask the author?

Comment: I've searched in all the application script and it is not used at all.
Does using fixed string in the scripts fix the problem ?

Comment: It should do, but I would be wary of making changes if you cannot test it.